# Double-clicking .sh file on KDE fails to run the script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, script, kde

I have a simple .sh script on my Desktop that fixes a minor annoyance with my second display. If I open Konsole, and type ./script.sh, it runs perfectly. But if I double click that .sh file - it fails to run, or runs only half of that script if I modify it. How do I make it run completely when double clicking it?

Here is the source:

```
#!/bin/bash
kscreen-doctor output.DP-3.position.0,0 output.DP-2.position.1920,-10
kscreen-doctor output.DP-3.disable
kquitapp5 plasmashell
kstart5 plasmashell
```

Comment: Are you in the situation of [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1379730/963426) or [this post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/643270/unable-to-run-sh-files-by-double-clicking-them) ?

Answer (score 0):

If you launched this script from a shell spawned from a child of `plasmashell`, the script will be terminated at line 4:

`kquitapp5 plasmashell`

Example:

[image: Screenshot of Spawned Shells]

AFAIK you may not have an option other than launching it as a service. If you are using `systemd`, a *System Unit* allows you to specify `After=` directive which you can use to indicate that the script be launched after UI is initialized.

Example:

```
[Unit]
Description=Run my script after UI is initialized
After=graphical.target
Before=
DefaultDependencies=no

[Service]
ExecStart=/path/to/your/script.sh
RemainAfterExit=no
```